# Purpose of dotnetRunMessages in launchSettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

In ASP.NET Core 5 the template provides this in `launchSettings.json`:

```json
"MyProject": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "dotnetRunMessages": "true",    // <<<<<<<<
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
},
```

`dotnetRunMessages` is not documented anywhere. What does it do?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The whole purpose of this setting, which indeed is not yet officially documented anywhere as far as I can tell, is to give some immediate feedback upon running `dotnet run` or `dotnet watch` inside of a terminal.

Without it set to `true`, on the first run after creating a new .NET core/ .NET 5 app, it might take a few seconds before some actual text feedback is shown, which might confuse the user.

It was started by this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/12227, where  you can find more details about the reasoning behind it.

---

Beside that, if you want to leverage the power of `dotnet watch` inside VS 2019, it's also better to have this flag set to `true`, since the messages that get to the console seem to be more verbose.

```json
"API Watch": {
  "commandName": "Executable",
  "executablePath": "dotnet",
  "commandLineArgs": "watch run",
  "workingDirectory": "$(ProjectDir)",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  },
  "dotnetRunMessages": true
}
```

Comment: Intellisense says: "Set to true to display a message when building."